# How can I get form values by loops in PHP

Tags: php, html

How can I get only the `test#` inputs without the email and password by

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="passsword" name="passsword">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 1" name="test#1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 2" name="test#2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 3" name="test#3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 4" name="test#4">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 5" name="test#5">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 6" name="test#6">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 7" name="test#7">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 8" name="test#8">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 9" name="test#9">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test 10" name="test#10">
    <button name="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I tried **foreach** but it gets all values

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to name all the fields `test[]`. Then `$_POST['test']` in PHP will be an array with all the values that you can simply do a `foreach()` on. Also, you need to show us what you've tried so far and explain where you're stuck. We're glad to help you with specific issues with your implementation, but we're not here to write it all for you (which a proper answer to this would require)

Comment: I assume you're talking about looping through the POST array? During looping you can filter for only keys which start with test. Or use a regular expression to filter up front. Or do as the above says and use an array in the HTML.

Comment: thank you, magnus Eriksson, I fix it u can see it in the answers section.
thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter by array key:

```
$testFields = array_filter($_POST, function($key){
    return strpos($key, 'test#') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

But I would instead suggest (as written in the comments) that you name your fields "test[]" and iterate over those:

```
foreach($_POST['test'] as $val){

}
```

PHP automatically gives you an array of fields with "[]" at the end of their name.

Answer (score 2):

You can name all same inputs with same name like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="test 2" name="test[]">
```

and then in php you can get input as

```
if($_POST['test']){
    foreach($_POST['test'] as $test){
        print_r($test)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $value = $i . '#test';
        echo $_GET[$value]."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work though? This would generate keys like `1#test` while the inputs you've posted in the question are named: `test#1`.